# Excluding nodes and their children using an xpath expression

Tags: xpath

Given this xml

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

I'd like to exclude `actors` and all the `actor` elements.

This xpath

```
/root/*[not(self::actors)]
```

returns

```
<foo:singers xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/">
    <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
    <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
    <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
</foo:singers>
```

whereas I want

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

- Using `/*[not(self::actors)]` returns the whole document without removing anything.
- Using `/*[not(descendant-or-self::actors)]` returns `NO MATCH!` on the test service at https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot remove nodes with XPath only. Are you looking for XSLT solution?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest at the moment I'm only using https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: @Andersson if it's not possible with XPath then I guess I am looking for an XSLT solution!

Comment: @ChrisW, `xpath-tester` is NOT Os. I asked about operating system (Linux, Windows, Osx)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes - but this is currently just a curiosity so my OS is pretty irrelevant?

Comment: @ChrisW, your OS may be weak for such tasks. This is trifling task for Linux command-line tools: one-liner in a few seconds ... But, good luck with your xpath-tester

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I assumed that the website would have the full XPath implementation. If you suspect this is not the case, perhaps you could suggest a better testing platform :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath expressions select nodes in a supplied input document. They can't make changes to the input document. The "root" element has "actors" as a child, and if you select it, it will still have "actors" as a child.

Similarly, if you select the foo:singers element, it will still have "root" as a parent.

Many client applications that display the result of an XPath expression choose to show the subtree rooted at the selected nodes, ignoring other nodes in the tree. That's just a way of displaying the results: you need to distinguish the nodes selected by the XPath expression from what is shown on screen when the results are displayed.

If you want to create a different tree in which the "root" does not have an "actors" child, you need XSLT or XQuery.